# Porting pygtk code to pygobject Gtk3: What is the equivalent of pango.SCALE_XX_SMALL

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to port a python gtk2 program which uses pango. I am stuck at trying to find the equavalent of pango.SCALE_XX_SMALL. The other pango constants translate for example from pango.WEIGHT_ULTRALIGHT to Pango.Weight.ULTRALIGHT but it seems SCALE_XX_SMALL does not follow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK They have not been introspected yet, check:

http://consciouslyusing.blogspot.com/2012/01/heads-up-missing-pango-text-scale.html

This is still the case in Ubuntu 12.04 included PyGobject version. The only solution right now is to define those constants yourself in your code. You can found the values at:

http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html#PANGO-SCALE-XX-SMALL:CAPS